# The new child element contains the parent error in JS

Tags: javascript, dom

I am coding a page to simulate loans in javascript. In the first input I request how many loans the user wants to request and that opens the second form to complete the rest of the data. But when I want to show him the result if he requested more than one, it shows me in the same container and I can't see the second loan. This error appears in the console: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'append' on 'Element': The new child element contains the parent.

This is the html code

```
    <div class="container principal pt-2 mb-3">
      <div class='row col-sm-12 mb-1'>
        <form id="formulario">          
          <div class="row col-sm-12 mb-1 d-flex justify-content-evenly">
            <label class="form-label col-12 col-lg-6 titulos" for='cantidadPrestamos'>¿Cuantos prestamos queres solicitar?</label>            
            <input class="col-12 col-lg-4 main m-2" id='cantidadPrestamos' name='full-name' type='number'/>
            <input class="col-12 col-lg-auto main m-2" type="submit" value="Enviar"> 
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="display" class="container principal mb-2 d-none">
      <div class='row col-sm-12 mb-1'>
        <form id="formPrestamo">
          <div class="titulos mb-3 p-1 pt-3"> Necesitamos estos datos para cotizar tu prestamo:
          </div>
          <div class="row col-sm-12 mb-1">
            <label class="form-label col-12 col-lg-4" for='capital'>Capital (Minimo $10.000)</label>
            <input class="col-12 col-lg-8 main mb-2" id='capital' name='full-name' type='number'/>
          </div>
          <div class='row col-sm-12 mb-1'>
            <label class="form-label col-12 col-lg-4" for='cuotas'>Cuotas (Maximo 60)</label>
            <input class="col-12 col-lg-8 main mb-2" id='cuotas' name='cuotas' type='number' />
          </div>
          <div class='row col-sm-12 mb-1'>
            <label class="form-label col-12 col-lg-4" for='interes'>Interes</label>
            <input class="col-12 col-lg-8 mb-2 main" id='interes' name='interes' type="number"></input>
          </div>
          <div class='row mb-3 d-flex justify-content-center'>
            <input class="col-12 col-lg-6 main m-2" type="submit" value="Enviar">
          </div>  
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contenedor"></div
```

and this is the js code:

```
let cantidadPrestamos = 0

let formulario = document.getElementById("formulario")
formulario.addEventListener("submit", validateForm)
function validateForm(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    let form = event.target
    cantidadPrestamos = form[0].value
    prestamo()
}

function Prestamo(capital, cantidadCuotas, interes, cuotaMes, devolucionTotal) {
    this.capital = capital
    this.cantidadCuotas = cantidadCuotas
    this.interes = interes
    this.cuotaMes = cuotaMes
    this.devolucionTotal = devolucionTotal
}



function prestamo(){

    let contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedor")
    function classContenedor() {
        contenedor.className= "container principal subtitulos"
        contenedor.append(contenedor)
    }

    if(cantidadPrestamos<=2){

        let display = document.getElementById("display")
        display.classList.remove("d-none")

        let prestamos = []

        for(let i = 0; i < cantidadPrestamos; i++){

            let prestamo = new Prestamo(0,0,0,0,0)

            prestamo.capital = 0
            prestamo.cantidadCuotas = 0
            prestamo.interes = 0

            let formPrestamo = document.getElementById("formPrestamo")
            formPrestamo.addEventListener("submit", validateFormPrestamo)
            function validateFormPrestamo(event){
                event.preventDefault()
                let formPrestamo = event.target
                prestamo.capital = formPrestamo[0].value
                prestamo.cantidadCuotas = formPrestamo[1].value
                prestamo.interes = formPrestamo[2].value / 100
                prestar()

            }

            function prestar(){

                function tasa (interes){
                return (1 + interes) ** (1/12) - 1
                }; 
                function cuotaMensual (capital, interes, cuotas){
                prestamo.cuotaMes = (tasa(interes) * capital) / (1 - (1 + tasa(interes)) ** - cuotas)
                }; 
                function devolucionTotal(cuotaMensual, cuotas){
                prestamo.devolucionTotal = cuotaMensual * cuotas    
                };

                

                if(prestamo.capital >= 10000){
                    if(prestamo.cantidadCuotas <=60){
                        tasa(prestamo.interes)
                        cuotaMensual(prestamo.capital, tasa(prestamo.interes), prestamo.cantidadCuotas)
                        devolucionTotal(prestamo.cuotaMes, prestamo.cantidadCuotas) 
                        prestamos.push(prestamo)  

                   }
                   else{                        
                        contenedor.innerHTML="Excediste la cantidad de cuotas habilitadas"
                        classContenedor()
                   } 
                }
                else{
                    contenedor.innerHTML="El monto solicitado es insuficiente. El minimo es $10.000"
                    classContenedor()
                }
             
                for (const prestamo of prestamos){                    
                        contenedor.innerHTML=`<h3>Solicitaste: $${prestamo.capital}</h3>
                        <p>el interes que queres pagar es ${prestamo.interes * 100}%</p>
                        <p>en: ${prestamo.cantidadCuotas} cuotas</p>
                        <p>vas a pagar: $${prestamo.cuotaMes.toFixed(2)}</p>
                        <p>vas a devolver en total $${prestamo.devolucionTotal.toFixed(2)}</p>`
                    classContenedor() 
                }   
            }
    }
}
    else{
        contenedor.innerHTML='El maximo de prestamos a solicitar es 2'
        classContenedor()
    }
}
```

thanks to all and apologies for the extension of the code, it is my first question in stackoverflow